# Ошибка в версии MySQL

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить такую ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #3' at line 1

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password = '$password'")  or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($result) or die(mysql_error());

if($count==1) {
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($result) or die("бла-бла");
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:login_success.php");
$_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo->id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo->username;

}
```

Comment: Ну неправильно запрос делаешь.
в студию запрос к мускулу.

Comment: измените тему на "Туплю с PHP и MySql" нужно написать за меня скрипт.

Comment: мде...

     header('Location:/...')

А потом пишет в сессию... Странно **пчему-же не работает?:D**

Comment: @AlexWindHope, повторю и для вас) После `header('Location:...')` перенаправления не происходит, а происходит тогда, когда отработал весь файл и браузер завершил прием данных.

    header('Location: http://hashcode.ru/');
    sleep(20);
    exit;

Comment: и делать header Location не в конце это нормально по вашему?..

Comment: Нет, но ошибкой это тоже не является) По-хорошему их всегда парой пишут,

    header('Location: /away/');
    exit;

или даже функцию типа redirect для этого оформляют. Но... это последнее, чем можно упрекать ТСа) Ибо если убрать хотя бы явные ошибки, бред, осьминожье форматирование ("8 рук и все из ж--ы"), я бы ему это простил))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жесть если ты так и дальше будешь писать код то ппц.

Попробуй так, но проверять работу скрипта не возьмусь, ибо времени жалко на такой код, пусть и в три строчки, но как написан!!!

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='".$username."' and `password` = '".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());      
     if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) { 
      $userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($result) or die("бла-бла"); 
      session_register("username"); // это тебе для чего? если ты ничего в них не пишешь кроме как username постоянно
      session_register("password"); // это тебе для чего? если ты ничего в них не пишешь кроме как password постоянно
      $_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo->id; 
      $_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo->username;
      header("location:login_success.php");

}
```

**//UPD** обновил, но с такими успехами, ты долго будешь писать свои скрипты и делать дебаги.
Где у тебя **session_start();**

В общем учи мат часть, ошибки в БД точно не будет, а вот написанный коряво код - копай в эту сторону.

Comment: я так уже пробивал , я задаю здесь вопрос когда уже все перебрал

Comment: Внимательно посмотри на код! и именно так и попробуй.

Comment: ок, пробую

Comment: не-а, не работает !

Comment: Ошибка осталась? или уже что-то другое не работает?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

что за бред?

**Добавлено.**

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1){
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) or die("бла-бла");
$_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo['id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo['username'];
header("location:login_success.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: а как нужно?

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: 2@Elime Твоё работать тоже не будет ;)

Comment: почему это?

Comment: потому это=) и это у меня еще бред -_-

Comment: если у тебя не бред, тогда объясни мне свои же строчки кода:
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
что это означает? зачем вообще нужно?
дальше: 
mysql_fetch_object 
чем mysql_fetch_assoc не угодил? или решил показать свои "знания" ООП?
дальше:
session_register("username"); session_register("password");
зачем? достаточно присвоить значение для переменной сессии.
дальше: 
header("location:login_success.php"); 
зачем перенаправлять пользователя до(!) присваивания значений для глобальных переменных?!
P.s твоего кода и врагу не пожелаешь..

Comment: Для форматирования в комментарии можно (как и в ответе) вводить 4 пробела в начале строки.
    форматировано

Comment: 2 @Elime потому что

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE     username='$username' and password = '$password'") or     die(mysql_error()); if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)

в одном месте у тебя $sql в другом $result

Comment: @avp, спасибо, понял
неплохо было бы написать где-то о разметке, а то я искал, так и не нашел

@Shrek ага, я заметил, код - ужас

Comment: @Elime, после `header` перенаправления не происходит.

Comment: @Elime, чтобы не было не относящегося к вопросу флуда, как сейчас =) Можно удалять наименее существенные комментарии и писать снова, но не приветствуется.